# Limit open ports in Linux

Tags: linux, security

I know that We can limit open ports by Linux firewall. In some cases, we also need to restrict an application to bind to only a specific port. Is there any security feature or application to do this?
for example, I have a goo-app binary that should bind to the 8080 port but not any other ports.

Comment: This is done in to the config of application. What is the app you talk about?

Comment: Do you want to run the application as restricted on demand? Or do you want to administratively restrict any future instance of the application, run by any user? If the former than I guess `firejail --net=… --netfilter=… …`. I haven't tested, so just a comment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If the port is configurable, you can change it in the config file.  Restrict write access to the config file to trusted users.

Comment: Dunno where all the close votes are coming from. A Mandatory Access Control module like SELinux can do this, though I'm not familiar with the specifics.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is going to be painful, but it could work.
Generally, you can get source code for any Linux program.

1. Download the source code
2. Change the source code
3. Re-compile
4. Install the new version.

Needless to say depending on the program #2 could take a lot of time.

Comment: Closed source programs do exists on Linux. Also recompiling large programs is not that simple. It can take you days just to prepare the build environment without making any change to the source code...